# Row Edit event handler issue

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  
        style="height: 121px; width: 175px" BackColor="White" 
        BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" 
        onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" SelectText="Edit" ShowEditButton="true" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblCpuName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cpuname") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cpuname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>



        <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("status") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("status") %>'>></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>


protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.Text;
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
            TextBox txt = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox2");
            SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["CpuName"].DefaultValue = txt.Text;
            SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["cpuid"].DefaultValue = "3";
            SqlDataSource1.Update();
            BindGridView();

        }
```

I am getting a object reference not set to an object on the textbox txt. I am not able to get the textbox2 in my gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.NewEditIndex];
TextBox txt = row.Cells[1].Controls[1] as TextBox;  
If (txt!= null)
{
    SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["CpuName"].DefaultValue = txt.Text;
    SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["cpuid"].DefaultValue = "3";
    SqlDataSource1.Update();
    BindGridView();
}
```

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'.

Comment: Can you tell me which column this cpuName field appears in Gridview?

Comment: It appears in the second column

Comment: I mean at runtime which column does it appear. is it appears as the 3rd column while running the application?

Comment: You havent updated. Its still giving the same label conversion erros

Comment: Then either you can check in the immediate window while in debugging mode for how many controls are there in that cell with    `row.Cells[1].Controls.Count;` and verify the index of the TextBox control or you can try one more time with   `TextBox txt = row.Cells[1].Controls[2] as TextBox;` this code.

Answer (score 0):

Why you just don't get directly the textbox value? is this a great problem?

```
 ...
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["CpuName"].DefaultValue = row.Columns["CpuName"].Value;
...
```

I don't know that this works, because I'm a C#-er, and basically work on winform not on web apps

Answer (score 0):

First, here is the snippet from MSDN, RowEditing topic:

> The RowEditing event is raised when a
>   row's Edit button is clicked, but
>   before the GridView control enters
>   edit mode. This enables you to provide
>   an event-handling method that performs
>   a custom routine, such as canceling
>   the edit operation, whenever this
>   event occurs.

To resolve the problem, handle the RowUpdating event for this purpose.  There is an example which should be helpful to you at:

[GridView.RowEditing event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting.aspx)

Also, I believe you should use the Bind word to bind your TextBox to a field:

'>

For more details, please refer to the [Data-Binding Expressions Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx)